# how to insert a text file in hosts.allow or hosts.deny?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, acl

So I read in man page of hosts.deny that i can input files in /etc/hosts.allow or hosts.deny to input ip addresses which i want to block or deny.

So i tried doing this in hosts.allow

```
sshd:   ALL EXCEPT /root/denylist
```

in this denylist I add or remove IPs dynamically using script.
denylist is something like this

```
31.101.16.127   
31.101.16.45
```

But it is not working and i am still able to access through those ips.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

hosts.allow should be written like this

```
sshd:/root/denylist:deny
sshd:all
```

and the deny list can be like this

```
31.101.16.127   
31.101.16.45
```

I put this in hosts.deny

```
ALL:ALL@ALL
```

and now its working properly and banning IPs in the denylist

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding IP's in hosts.allow then it will allow the IP's. If you don't want to access those IP's put them in hosts.deny. If you want to add in hosts.allow use EXCEPT.

Comment: I want to use EXCEPT. How should I proceed?

Comment: ALL EXCEPT /root/denylist

Comment: that is what i had earlier done in the question. It does  not seems to work,

Comment: Did you write sshd:   ALL EXCEPT /root/denylist
or ALL EXCEPT /root/denylist?

Comment: i wrote sshd: ALL EXCEPT /root/denylist

Answer (score 0):

Add to hosts.deny:

`sshd: /root/denylist`

I've never gotten "ALL EXCEPT /file" to work, not sure why, might be a bug.

You could try this in your hosts.deny for your specific case:

`ALL EXCEPT sshd: ALL
sshd: /root/denylist`

Comment: problem hosts.allow has sshd:   ALL so it is not checking in hosts.deny. and in hosts.deny its ALL:ALL@ALL. That is why i wanted to use EXCEPT tag.

Comment: ow, you block everything, and then allow SSH?

Comment: no, I only allow ssh and block everything. Then in ssh i block the ips from where attacks are coming.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I said :) anyway, check the second part of my answer, blocks everything except sshd, blocks only the blocklist for sshd

Comment: I have tried your solution. But it is not working. 31.101.16.137 is in denylist but i am still able to ssh from that ip.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it myself and it works with my IP. I'm lost. Sorry.